# Disable change wallpaper. MacOS

Tags: objective-c, macos

I`m use CGDisplayStream for capture video from user screen. I want disable user wallpaper for optimize video size. I can change wallpaper or i can set background color, but user can change that. How i can disable change wallpaper? Or may be is can disable wallpaper?

Comment: Is the application for general people to use?  If so, you can't, and you have no right to do that in the first place.

Comment: Yes, this application for general people. TeamViewer some do it that, i thik that possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just create window with level

```
[window setLevel:CGWindowLevelForKey(kCGDesktopWindowLevelKey)];
```